# How to note if a missing entry for a variable has a non-missing entry above it?

Tags: r, validation, dplyr, data-manipulation, tidyr

I have a `df` described as follows:

```
df<-read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text = 
                 "STUDY_ID      ID  diseased_vessel left_main_stenosis left_circumflex
               1 1526817 1 2                 NA              40
               2 1527547 1 NA                NA             100
               3 1528483 2 4                 70              70
               4 1554085 3 NA                NA             100
               5 1554099 3 3                 30             100
               6 1554100 4 1                 40             100
               7 1554229 4 3                 NA             NA")
```

Where we have 5 varibles and 7 records. Specifically, we have 4 unique `ID`, where each can have more than 1 `STUDY_ID`.

I would like to check which are the `ID`s that have missing variable values for either `diseased_vessel`, `left_main_stenosis` or `left_circumflex` for the later `STUDY_ID` but not the earlier one, and filter them.

Of course, we will look at `ID`s that have more than 1 `STUDY_ID`, i.e. 1, 3 and 4.

1. For 1, he has missing `diseased_vessel` for the later one but not the earlier one. "Later" corresponds to a bigger value of `STUDY_ID`. Hence, included.
2. For 3, he has no missing values for the 3 variables. Hence, excluded.
3. For 4, he has missing values for `left_main_stenosis` and `left_circumflex` for the later part but the not the earlier one. Hence, included.

The final dataset should look like:

```
df<-read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text = 
                 "STUD_ID      ID  diseased_vessel left_main_stenosis left_circumflex
           1 1526817 1 2                 NA              40
           2 1527547 1 NA                NA             100
           3 1554100 4 1                 40             100
           4 1554229 4 3                 NA             NA")
```

I dont really know how to start.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps using `filter_at` from `dplyr` would be helpful here?

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  arrange(STUDY_ID, .by_group = TRUE) %>%
  filter_at(vars(diseased_vessel:left_circumflex),
            any_vars(!is.na(first(.)) & is.na(last(.))))

#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#> # Groups:   ID [2]
#>   STUDY_ID    ID diseased_vessel left_main_stenosis left_circumflex
#>      <int> <int>           <int>              <int>           <int>
#> 1  1526817     1               2                 NA              40
#> 2  1527547     1              NA                 NA             100
#> 3  1554100     4               1                 40             100
#> 4  1554229     4               3                 NA              NA
```

Comment: Nice, but not sure it'll work if there're more than 2 rows per ID.

Comment: @AdielLoinger, that's a fair point. I think it will work for more than 2 rows per `ID` *but* only on the assumption the OP wants to keep records where the lowest `STUDY_ID` was non-missing and the highest `STUDY_ID` was `NA` which probably isn't ideal. Perhaps someone else can improve on this if this isn't what the OP is looking for

Answer (score 0):

you can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
setorder(df, ID, -STUDY_ID)
ids <- df[, any(sapply(.SD, function(x) is.na(x[1]) & !is.na(x[2]))), by = 'ID', .SDcols = c('diseased_vessel', 'left_main_stenosis', 'left_circumflex')][V1 == TRUE, ID]
df[ID %in% ids]
```